Basic HTTP Auth and white listed IP in site config
I have a virtual host in Apache2 (2.4.52) and I would like to have something like this in the site config (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled):
<Location />
    # Only allow whitelisted IPs
    Include /etc/apache2/whitelist.conf

    # Ask for password if ip is whitelisted
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Satisfy all
</Location>

The idea is to first filter on IP with whitelist.conf and the ask for a password in /etc/apache2/.htpasswd.
whitelist.conf looks like this:
Require ip 127.0.0.1

Is this wrong?

The solution to this problem is to use nested requirements:
<Location />
    <RequireAll>
        <RequireAny>
            Include /etc/apache2/whitelist.conf
        </RequireAny>
    
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    
        Require valid-user
    </RequireAll>
</Location>

